# Retrieving multiple records by email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class called Membership. There could be multiple records with the same email. To retrieve all Membership records by email, I am creating an index on email and doing:

```
Membership.where(email: "example@example.com")
```

How expensive is the above operation? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: That's the way to do it efficiently. You are all set!

Comment: Expensive in contrast with what?...that just resolves to raw SQL, and it's the most direct SQL command you could make for what you want. Unless you have some other attribute that's identical to email, that's all you've got.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way is with group query like this:

```
Membership.select(:email).group(:email).having("count(*) > 1")
```

This will generate following query

```
SELECT "memberships"."email" FROM "memberships" GROUP BY "memberships"."email" HAVING (count(*) > 1)
```

That should work on PG and MySQL.

Hope it helps

EDIT

if you want to see duplicates, you can do this (put a count at the end)

```
Membership.select(:email).group(:email).having("count(*) > 1").count
```

This will give a collection with each email and number of duplicates listed like this:

{ 'some@duplicate.com' => 2, ...etc}